# How can i calculate output range for this animation in react native with reanimated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm trying to re-implement this material component in react native with reanimated:
https://m3.material.io/components/carousel/overview

Here is my implementaion, which is full of bugs:
https://snack.expo.dev/@arasrezaie/material-carousel

I do not know how to do it correctly.
react native animation GOATS,any help appreciated!!
thanks